# Como utilizar echo em uma query com prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

Gostaria de saber como utilizar echo em uma query com prepared statement, para poder visualizar como ela foi montada pelo php antes de ser executada, facilitando assim a vizualização do erro no momento em que é feito o bind_param...

Exemplo:

```
$Apagar = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM mensagens WHERE id IN (?)");
$Apagar->bind_param('s',$Mensagens);
print_r($Apagar);exit;
```

Gostaria que isso me retornasse a query por extenso e não apenas os resultados da execução dela, exemplo:

```
DELETE FROM mensagens WHERE id in (1,2,3,...);
```

Procurei por uma solução e a unica que achei foi usando Zend então fica inviavel para mim...
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não me parece que exista uma forma 'nativa' de fazer isto. Principalmente uma que tenha em conta o escape adequado de valores. Tanto quanto eu sei (embora nunca tenha verificado no código), o MySQLi nunca produz a query completa por extenso e envia mesmo os dados em separado.

Comment: se não existe uma forma nativa talvez exista uma forma caseira de se fazer isso, pois no zend existe um função nativa dele para isso, mas não sei como desenvolver isso no php puro para conseguir avaliar a query

Comment: [Isto](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.adapter.html) sugere que o Zend usa o pdo_mysql e não o mysqli. O PDO tem o `queryString` que pode ser usado como ponto de partida.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962986/how-to-echo-a-mysqli-prepared-statement

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link, O cara ta usando mysqli

Comment: O código na pergunta serve para debugging mas cuidado que não serve para produção: não deve usar isso como código de outra query porque ele não faz escape aos parâmetros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se o objetivo é ver os valores correspondentes as interrogações essa função de substituição.

```
function setValor($consulta, $valores){
    $count = substr_count($consulta, '?');
    $interrogacoes = array_fill('0', $count, '/\?/');
    $consulta_original = preg_replace($interrogacoes, $valores, $consulta, 1);

    return $consulta_original;
}
```

[substr_count()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-count.php) retorna o número de ocorrências encontradas(no caso `?`) de uma string passada como segundo argumento dentro de outra(`$consulta`). [array_fill()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-fill.php) cria uma array com a regex de substituição `'/\?/'` sendo que o número de elementos será definido por `$count` e por ultimo ocorre a substituição com [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php), funciona da seguinte maneira ele busca pela primeira regex e substitui pelo primeiro valor encontrado em `$valor` e assim sucessivamente até chegar o final do array. O último argumento `1` significa o número maximo de substituições efetuadas.

exemplo:

```
$consultas = array(
            'INSERT INTO tabela(nome, email, idade, endereco) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
            'SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id IN(?,?)',
            'DELETE FROM tabela where id = ?'
) ;

$valores = array(
                array('joao', 'joao@gmail.com.', '20', 'rua xx'),
                array(99, 70),
                array(48)
);


$i =0;
foreach($consultas as $item){
    echo  setValor($item, $valores[$i]) .'<br>';
    $i++;
}
```

saida:

```
INSERT INTO tabela(nome, email, idade, endereco) VALUES (joao,joao@gmail.com.,20,rua xx)
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id IN(99,70)
DELETE FROM tabela where id = 48
```

Comment: Eu falei que tinha uma solução caseira :D

Answer (score 7):

O que você deseja fazer não é possível via php-mysqli.

Repare nos atributos de [mysqli_stmt na documentação](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php), no máximo você vai conseguir extrair o **$errno** (int) ou o **$error** (string).

Caso a query chegue a ser disparada (mesmo que com erros), para fins de debug eu acho bacana ativar o log de queries do MySQL. Aí você pode acompanhar em tempo real com um tail -f no arquivo de log. Veja só como habilitar:

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = "FILE";
SET GLOBAL general_log_file = "/tmp/mysql.log";
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Comment: acho que no fim é o melhor meio que vai ter