# Como printar a instrução SQL que está sendo enviada ao banco?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Gostaria de saber como printar uma SQL para fins de controle da instrução que está sendo enviada ao banco de dados:

```
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM imovel WEHRE CATEGORIA = 'APARTAMENTO'");
```

Como printar a instrução SQL que está sendo enviada ao banco?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Baseado nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8930/91), criei uma classe para ver os valores de um prepared statement, basicamente é feita substituição dos placholders pelos valores. No [**exemplo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/x2vs-ca6z) é mostrado como chamar a classe.

```
<?php

class queryDebugger{
    const QUESTION_MARK = '/\?/';
    const NAMED_PLACE_HOLDER = '/:[a-z0-9_]+/i';

    private $placeHolder;

    public function setValues($query, $values){

        if(count($values) == 0)  throw new exception('Empty values');

        $this->setplaceHolder($query);
        $placeHolder = array_fill(0, count($values), $this->placeHolder);
        preg_match_all($this->placeHolder, $query, $queryPlaceHolders);

        if(count($placeHolder) != count($queryPlaceHolders[0])){
            throw new exception ('The number of placeholders does not match with values in: ' .$query. ' values: '.count($placeHolder));
        }

        $newQuery = preg_replace($placeHolder, $values, $query, 1);

        return $newQuery;
    }

    private function setPlaceHolder($query){
        (preg_match(queryDebugger::QUESTION_MARK, $query)) ? 
           $this->placeHolder = queryDebugger::QUESTION_MARK :
           $this->placeHolder = queryDebugger::NAMED_PLACE_HOLDER;
    }

}
```

O método `setValues()` funciona da seguinte forma primeiro descobre qual é o tipo de marcação se é uma interrogaçãou(`?`) ou um nome(`:param`), [array_fill()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) cria uma array onde os elementos são as regex das marcações(`/\?/` ou `/:[a-z0-9_]+/i`) depois [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) retorna um array(terceiro parâmetro) de todas as ocorrencias encontradas em `$query`.

```
 $newQuery = preg_replace($placeHolder, $values, $query, 1);
```

[preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) substitui as marcações pelos respectivos valores o número um(último parâmetro) é o limite de substiuições que devem ser feitas.

Answer (score 12):

Assim

```
echo $sql ->queryString
```