# Bug no PDO? Tabela desaparece após comando INSERT, como Debugar?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

#### Introdução

Estou criando uma [biblioteca com alguns "métodos mágicos" em cima do PDO](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionPDO), já [fiz isso com o MySQLi](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionMSi) e funcionou lindamente. A intensão é utilizar em um [Framework que estou construindo](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/Base), enfim chega de jabá.

#### Problema

Misteriosamente minha tabela de testes está sendo excluída logo após (ou durante, não sei ao certo) um `INSERT`.

[image: BUG: Tabela sumiu]

#### Código

Arquivo: **teste.php**

```
 <?php

     $con = New ConnectionPDO;

     echo '<pre>';
     var_dump( $con->getTables() );
     echo '</pre>';

     $r = $con->insert('tab_teste',Array('id'=>1,'name' => 'First Record', 'col3' => 'test '))->execute();
     $log .= ($r ? 'Success' : 'Fail') . PHP_EOL;

     echo '<pre>';
     echo $con->lastSQL() . PHP_EOL;
     echo '</pre>';

     echo '<pre>';
     var_dump( $con->getTables() );
     echo '</pre>';
 ?>
```

Classe: **ConnectionPDO**

```
 <?php

 class ConnectionPDO extends PDO {

    function __construct($dsn, $username = NULL, $password = NULL, $options = NULL) {
       parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
       $this->LoadDriverMethods();
    }

    private function LoadDriverMethods(){
       $driver = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'drivers' . 
                           DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sqldriver.' . 
                           strtolower($this->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME)) . '.php';

       if (!is_file($driver))
          throw new Exception('Não foi possível carregar os métodos do driver', 1);

       require_once $driver;
       $this->driver = new SQLDriver();
    }

    public function insert($table, $data) {
       $this->lastSQL = $this->driver->insert($table, $data);

       $stmt = $this->prepare($this->lastSQL);

       $this->driver->setParams($this->stmt);

       $this->log .= $this->driver->flushLog();

       return $this->stmt;
    }

 }
 ?>
```

Classe: **SQLDriver**

```
 <?php
 class SQLDriver implements DriverInterface {

    public function insert($table, $data){

       $this->clearParams();

       $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` ";

       $colunms = Array();

       $values  = Array();

       foreach ($data as $col => $value) {
          $colunms[] = "`{$col}`";
          $values[]  = '?';

          $this->addParam($col, $value);
       }

       $sql .= '(' . implode(', ', $colunms) . ') VALUES (' . implode(', ', $values) . ');';

       $this->log .= $sql . PHP_EOL;

       return $sql;
    }

    public function addParam($key, $value){
       //$this->params[':'.$key] = $value;
       $this->params[] = $value;
    }

    public function setParams(PDOStatement $stmt){
       $params = $this->getParams();
       $this->log .=  'Setando Parâmetros: '.PHP_EOL;
       if (is_array($params) && !empty($params)){
          foreach ($params as $param => $value){
             $stmt->bindValue($param+1, $this->prepareParam($value), $this->getParamType($value));
             $this->log .=  $param+1 . ' => ' . $this->prepareParam($value) . PHP_EOL;
          }
       }
       $this->log .= PHP_EOL.'-----------------------------'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
    }

 }
 ?>
```

Coloquei apenas o código em torno do erro. O código completo pode ser visto nos links:

- [Arquivo teste.php](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionPDO/blob/5700b7c711a98689a0c04de16a6b066027c47dae/teste.php#L146)
- [Classe ConnectionPDO](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionPDO/blob/5700b7c711a98689a0c04de16a6b066027c47dae/ConnectionPDO.php#L49)
- [Classe SQLDriver](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionPDO/blob/5700b7c711a98689a0c04de16a6b066027c47dae/drivers/sqldriver.mysql.php#L28)

A não ser que alguém baixe o código e fique testando e procurando não creio que encontrará o problema tão facilmente, então a pergunta principal aqui é, **como debugar o PDO?** A secundária é, **o que pode estar ocasionando isso?** A terceira, **por que?**

Comment: Talvez quando tiver mais tempo, inspecione o `script`. Para já, boa sorte.

Comment: Como assim inspecionar o script?

Comment: Ver o que tem de errado *-*, disseste que tem um erro/problema, que pode ser localizado apenas com testes.

Comment: Aparece algum erro para vc? estou testando e aqui as vezes da falha na consulta.

Comment: Não aparece erro, apenas informa como se estivesse tudo bem. Por exemplo, repare que tem uma variável log, onde armazeno "success" ou "fail" desde o primeiro INSERT, pra mim aparece todas as vezes success e depois os scripts de DELETE e UPDATE funcionam normalmente também. Porém apartir do primeiro INSERT a tabela já desapareceu do banco, por isso não estou entendendo, se desse erro seria mais justificável.

Comment: Então a unica coisa que notei de errado foi no insert, de PDOConnection, é criada uma variáve temporarioa `$stmt` e vc passa pra frente `$this->stmt`. https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionPDO/blob/master/ConnectionPDO.php#L52 , o `select()` tbm tem isso.

Comment: Caraca, agora explica tudo, já que o statement armazenado na variável `$this->stmt` é o do método executado anteriormente `$con->drop()`... :O Eu passei o dia todo e não reparei isso. Eu to e casa agora, não tem como testar, mas se você mudar ali pra `$this->stmt` em vez de `$stmt` funciona o `$con->select`la em baixo?

Comment: testei dessa forma http://pastebin.com/w5PRTcHM , com as modificações que sugeri no comentário anterior.

Comment: Beleza acho que é esse o problema, amanhã eu testo. Tenho que terminar um trabalho da faculdade aqui. Valeu, se quiser postar como resposta amanhã quando eu testar eu marco.

Comment: Saida do código é [essa](http://i.stack.imgur.com/um3aK.jpg)

Comment: *-* Que interessante, ja transferi até o código com a esperança de poder ler hoje. Porém se for este o problema, não deve custar nadinha a resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parte do problema é o exemplo da pergunta ele não simula o sintoma da tabela sumir, já o [github](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionPDO/blob/5700b7c711a98689a0c04de16a6b066027c47dae/teste.php#L146) deixa claro.

### TL;DR

O método `insert()`, o `select` também, prepara a instrução sql passada porém retornam a consulta preparada anterior ou seja na combinação do teste `DROP TABLE` é executado duas vezes.

---

Montei um teste menor, fiz apenas uma alteração para evidenciar o problema,  mudei a visibilidade `$stmt` em `ConnectionPDO` de private para public só para teste, assim é possível ver qual foi a última consulta executada através de [queryString](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php#pdostatement.props.querystring) e fazer a comparação.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
$stmt = NULL;
function __autoload($class){
   if (class_exists($class)) return true;
   $dir = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
   $ext = '.php';
   if (file_exists($dir.$class.$ext)) require_once $dir.$class.$ext;
   else exit('Couldn\'t open class '.$class.'!');
}
$settings = Array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => 'localhost',
   'port'      => '3306',
   'schema'    => 'pdoweb2',
   'username'  => 'root',
   'password'  => 'root'
);
$dns = $settings['driver'] . ':host=' . $settings['host'] . 
                             ';port=' . $settings['port'] . 
                             ';dbname=' . $settings['schema'];
$con = new ConnectionPDO($dns, $settings['username'], $settings['password']);



$r = $con->drop('tab_teste');

    $fields = Array('id' => Array('type' => 'int', 'size' => '4', 'comment' => 'first key', 'auto' => true),
                    'name' => Array('type' => 'varchar', 'size' => '60', 'comment' => 'test name'),
                    'col3' => Array('type' => 'varchar', 'size' => '60', 'default' => NULL,'comment' => 'test name')
            );

    $sql =  'CREATE TABLE `tab_teste` (' . PHP_EOL .
            '   id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,' . PHP_EOL .
            '   name VARCHAR(60),' . PHP_EOL .
            '   col3 VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL' . PHP_EOL .
            ');';

    $r = $con->query($sql);

    echo 'getTables()<pre>';        
    print_r($con->getTables());
    echo '</pre>';

    $r = $con->insert('tab_teste',Array('id'=>1,'name' => 'First Record', 'col3' => 'test '))->execute();

    echo 'LastSQL: '. $con->lastSQL() .'<br>';
    echo 'Ultima consulta preparada: '. $con->stmt->queryString .'<br><br>';


    $r = $con->insert('tab_teste',Array('id'=>2,'name' => 'Second Record', 'col3' => 'test '))->execute();
    echo 'LastSQL: '. $con->lastSQL() .'<br>';
    echo 'Ultima consulta preparada: '. $con->stmt->queryString .'<br><br>';


    echo 'getTables()<pre>';        
    print_r($con->getTables());
    echo '</pre>';
```

A saída foi:

```
getTables()

Array
(
    [0] => tab_teste
)

LastSQL: INSERT INTO `tab_teste` (`id`, `name`, `col3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
Ultima consulta preparada: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tab_teste`;

LastSQL: INSERT INTO `tab_teste` (`id`, `name`, `col3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
Ultima consulta preparada: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tab_teste`;

getTables()

Array
(
)
```

A primeira instrução executada é um `drop()` nenhum problema ocorre, a próxima é um `insert()` aqui é onde o problema acontece, o insert é preparada e jogado em uma variável local `$stmt` e algumas linhas depois é retornado o mémbro `$this->stmt` que tem o drop processado anteriormente.

```
public function insert($table, $data) {
   $this->lastSQL = $this->driver->insert($table, $data);
   $stmt = $this->prepare($this->lastSQL); //<--- variável local
   $this->driver->setParams($this->stmt);
   $this->log .= $this->driver->flushLog();
   return $this->stmt; //<--- retorno da consulta anterior, o drop no caso
}

public function drop($table){
   $this->lastSQL = $this->driver->drop($table);
   $this->stmt = $this->prepare($this->lastSQL);
   $this->log .= $this->driver->flushLog();
   return $this->stmt;
}
```

Para corrigir isso faça a atribuição no mémbro no lugar da variável local, aplique a mudanção no `insert()` e `select()`.

Mude:

```
$stmt = $this->prepare($this->lastSQL);
```

Para:

```
$this->stmt = $this->prepare($this->lastSQL);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente bem. :D Pesquisei bastante saber como ver a query executada `$con->stmt->queryString`, mas só vi gente dizendo que não tinha como, pois a _query_ e os parâmetros eram enviados separadamente para o servidor... Agora é o DROP que não funciona... ¬¬

Comment: @KaduAmaral, o próximo de pegar os valores da consulta que cheguei [foi isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34811/91)

Comment: Bacana @rray, se não se importa utilizarei seu código nos métodos de debug, tudo bem?

Comment: @KaduAmaral, Pode usar, esse é objetivo :D