# Mostra como ficou a $query

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoal ja vi isso funcionando em algum lugar mas nao me lembro onde. e o seguinte quero dar um `echo` em meu codigo e exibir como ficou o insert no Mysql tipo

```
$query1 = $conn->query("INSERT INTO dados1 VALUES (NULL, '".$nome."')");
        $id_dados1 = $id_doutor;
        echo "$query1";
```

e quando eu dar o `echo` preciso que me retorne algo do tipo

```
INSERT INTO dados1 VALUES (01, Joao)
```

para que eu saiba como ficou o insert

Comment: Com o pdo? ou MySQLi? `$query1` tem o retorno da consulta ou um false mas não a string da consulta ...

Comment: Talvez [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34797/91) responda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem já pensou em "gerar" a query antes de executar? Algo como:

```
<?php
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO dados1 VALUES ('" . $nome . "');";
$query1 = $conn->query($sql1);
var_dump($query1);

echo $sql1; // Imprime SQL 1
?>
```

Até porque para imprimir usando o próprio retorno concerteza você terá que alterar sua classe *"$conn"* para gerar esse retorno.

Quanto ao último ID inserido ele só sabe qual é após fazer o INSERT, e para isso você pode usar uma função ou um novo SELECT para puxar esse último ID como:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dados1
```

Ou usar uma funão como disse o PHP possui a função [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php), ela vai ser descontinuada nas futuras versões do PHP, porém não sei o que existe dentro da sua classe *"$conn"* então você pode tomar ela como ponto de partida para tentar implementar dentro.