# Pegar campo mysql dinamicamente

Tags: php, mysql, query, select

criei um comando select com base em informações enviadas pelo usuário, ex:

```
$anoini = $_GET['anoini']; //variavel com ano escolhido pelo usuário
$anofim = 2016; //ano final é 2016

$s = 'SELECT pa_proc_id, procedimento, '; //inicio da query
while ($anoini < $anofim) { //laço para listar todos os anos
    $s = $s . 'SUM( pa_qtdapr * ( 1 - ABS( SIGN( CONVERT( SUBSTRING( pa_cmp, 1, 4 ) , signed ) - '.$anoini.' ) ) ) ) AS a'.$anoini.', '; //a cada ano, ele inclui uma linha na query
    $anoini++;
}
$s = $s . 'SUM( pa_qtdapr * ( 1 - ABS( SIGN( CONVERT( SUBSTRING( pa_cmp, 1, 4 ) , signed ) - '.$anofim.' ) ) ) ) AS a'.anofim.' '; //finaliza criando a linha com o ano atual
$s = $s . 'FROM sia WHERE pa_ufmun = "'.$ibge.'" and substring(pa_cmp,1,4) >= :anoini GROUP BY pa_proc_id'; //finaliza a query
```

**o código acima funciona perfeitamente** e me gera um resultado com alguns campos criados dinamicamente referentes a cada ano desde o indicado pelo usuário até 2016, ex:a2014, a2015, a2016

executo a query e crio o array:

```
$lista = $db->prepare($s) or trigger_error($db->error);
$lista->bindValue(":anoini",$GLOBALS['anoini']);
$lista->execute();
$GLOBALS['procedimento'] = $lista->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

minha dúvida é: como saber quais campos (a2014, a2015, etc) foram criados e como dar um "echo" neles?

**EDITADO**

dei um var_dump e o resultado foi esse abaixo:

```
array (size=130)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'pa_proc_id' => string '0101010010' (length=10)
      'procedimento' => string 'ATIVIDADE EDUCATIVA / ORIENTACAO EM GRUPO NA ATENCAO BASICA ' (length=60)
      'a2010' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2011' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2012' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2013' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2014' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2015' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2016' => string '67' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      'pa_proc_id' => string '0101020015' (length=10)
      'procedimento' => string 'ACAO COLETIVA DE APLICACAO TOPICA DE FLUOR GEL' (length=46)
      'a2010' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2011' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2012' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2013' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2014' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2015' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2016' => string '23' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=9)
      'pa_proc_id' => string '0101020031' (length=10)
      'procedimento' => string 'ACAO COLETIVA DE ESCOVACAO DENTAL SUPERVISIONADA' (length=48)
      'a2010' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2011' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2012' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2013' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2014' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2015' => string '0' (length=1)
      'a2016' => string '184' (length=3)
```

como listar os **nomes dos campos, não os valores** (nesse caso de a2010 até a2016)?

abraços.

Comment: Seria isso [Como printar a instrução SQL que está sendo enviada ao banco?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34797/91) ?

Comment: Veja se isso aqui resolve pra você: http://pastebin.com/NnAG5p4R

Comment: não, a questão é saber quais campos foram criados (a2014, a2015, etc), pois os campos são criados de acordo com o ano escolhido pelo usuário. após descobrir os campos, então lista eles

Comment: Então, mas não é só vc fazer uma cópia do minimo e reproduzir o while?

Comment: @Sorack não entendi

Comment: Basicamente você já sabe os nomes dos campos pq quando vc faz o while do ano já coloca ele no `as` da tabela. Então é só vc guardar ele em um array ou reproduzir o while

Comment: acrescentei mais informações

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RESOLVI:

uso o código a seguir em loop para saber se os campos existem e dou um echo neles.

```
if (isset($linha[0]['a'.$anoini])){
    echo $linha[0]['a'.$anoini];
}
```

abraço a todos que ajudaram

Answer (score 0):

você vai executar um loop e dentro deste loop vai trazer o resultado no seu echo.

Exemplo:

```
while($rs = $lista->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $var1 = $rs['campo_da_tabela'];
  ...
}
```

Comment: a questão é justamente saber qual o 'campo_da_tabela' pois o mesmo é criado de acordo com o ano escolhido pelo usuário

Comment: alterei minha pergunta, veja se pode me ajudar. abraço.