# Como ver a query final que foi executada? PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, query, postgresql, pdo

Faço minhas consultas da seguinte maneira:

```
$sql = "Select * From minha_tabela Where meu_campo = :parametro";
$sql = $db->prepare($sql);
$sql->bindParam(":parametro", $parametro, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
```

Porém

```
echo $sql->rowCount(); //RETORNA ZERO
```

Gostaria de exibir minha *query* após ter passado pelo `bindParam` para verificar exatamente o que foi executado. Como posso recuperar ela?

Comment: Tem essa [reposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9150/91) que mostra como pegar os valores e substituir pelos placeholders é aplicavel ao PDO também, tem uma outra pergunta sobre o PDO porém ainda não achei.

Comment: [Como printar a instrução SQL que está sendo enviada ao banco?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34797/91)

Comment: `echo $sql->queryString;`