# Insert modo GET

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia,
 Este é o form de um formulário meu de perguntas:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="chk-gerente.php?nro_pergunta=<?php  echo $nro_pergunta; ?>" method="GET">
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Pergunta <?php echo"$ordem";?>/<?php echo"$totalpergunta";?></legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <center><h3><label><?php echo"$descpergunta";?></label></h3></center>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="resp" id="optionsRadios1" value="5">OTIMO        </label></div>
            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="resp" id="optionsRadios2" value="3">REGULAR      </label></div>
            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="resp" id="optionsRadios3" value="1">RUIM         </label></div>
            <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="resp" id="optionsRadios4" value="0">NAO APLICADO </label></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php
         $timestamp            = @mktime(date("H")-4, date("i"),date("s"),date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"),0);
         $DataCad              = gmdate("Y-m-d", $timestamp); // Gravar $DataCad no BD
         echo"<input type='hidden' name='loja'         id='loja'         value='$loja'>";
         echo"<input type='hidden' name='id_usuario'   id='id_usuario'   value='$id_usuario'>";
         echo"<input type='hidden' name='questionario' id='questionario' value='$questionario'>";
         echo"<input type='hidden' name='area'         id='area'         value='$area'>";
         echo"<input type='hidden' name='nro_pergunta' id='nro_pergunta' value='$nro_pergunta'>";     
         echo"<input type='hidden' name='DataCad'      id='DataCad'      value='$DataCad'>";
         echo"<input type='hidden' name='pergunta'     id='pergunta'     value='$idpergunta'>";
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Responder</button>
           </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
     </form>
```

Como estou passando um comando no action,como poderia ser meu insert no db?
 Tentei fazer no inicio da pagina com GET mais sem sucesso,alguma dica?

Comment: Você pode usar o valor passado por parâmetro pelo action do formpara dizer em qual a pergunta correspondente, o parâmetro do action, você também pode coletar por get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.
 Passei da seguinte forma:

```
 if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $loja         = $_GET ["loja"];
    $id_usuario  = $_GET ["id_usuario"]; 
    $questionario = $_GET ["questionario"];
    $area         = $_GET ["area"];
    $idpergunta   = $_GET ["pergunta"];   
    $resp         = $_GET ["resp"]; 
    $datacad      = $_GET ["data_cad"]; 

  $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO respostas 
  (resp_id,resp_loja,resp_usuario,resp_questionario,resp_area,resp_subgrupo,resp_pergunta_id,resp_resposta,resp_data,resp_status)
  VALUES 
  ('','$loja','$id_usuario','$questionario','$area','1','$idpergunta','$resp','$datacad','1')") 
   or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_query($sql_insert,$conexao); }
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Otacio, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Primeiro, você deve marcar a resposta aceita somente se ela realmente resolve o problema. Você marcou a outras resposta como "correta" porém isso só vai confundir pessoas que acessarem esta questão no futuro, já que ela simplesmente não responde à pergunta.

Comment: Segundo, embora você tenha resolvido o problema, concatenar parâmetros do usuário diretamente na consulta SQL é uma péssima prática. Sugiro você consultar como fazer *prepared statements*. Exemplos podem ser vistos [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88644/227), [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88683/227) e [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8930/227).